# Como fazer um insert no banco de dados a partir de um relacionamento muitos para muitos no typeorm

Tags: mysql, typeorm

Estou desenvolvendo um cadastro de profissionais onde cada profissional pode falar um ou mais idiomas, contudo ao salvar profissionais, os idiomas nao sao salvos

```
@Entity('idioma')
export class Idioma {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  lang: string;
  @Column()
  native: boolean;
}
```

```
@Entity('Profissional')
export class Profissional {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @Column()
  @IsOptional()
  phone: string;
  @Column()
  @IsOptional()
  celPhone: string;
  @Column()
  @IsOptional()
  sexo: string;
  @Column()
  @IsOptional()
  nasc: Date;
  @Column('bool')
  @IsOptional()
  fumante: boolean;
  @Column()
  @IsOptional()
  ocupation: string;
  @Column()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;
  @OneToMany(
    () => Idioma,
    idioma => idioma.id,
    {cascade: true}
  )
  lang: Idioma[];
  @Column()
  password: string;
  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5 })
  latitude: number;
  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5 })
  longitude: number;
  @Column('decimal', { precision: 2 })
  @IsOptional()
  workPrice: number;
}
```

```
async create(profissional: ProfissionalDto) {
    const errors = validate(profissional);
    
    
    profissional.password = bcrypt.hashSync(profissional.password, 12);
    const prof = this.profissionalRepository.save(profissional);
    
    return prof;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que faltou aí é que na entidade **Idioma**, faz,-se necessário a declaração dos relacionamentos, como pode ser visto na [documentação](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations):

> You can omit @JoinColumn in a @ManyToOne / @OneToMany relation. @OneToMany cannot exist without @ManyToOne. If you want to use @OneToMany, @ManyToOne is required. However, the inverse is not required: If you only care about the @ManyToOne relationship, you can define it without having @OneToMany on the related entity. Where you set @ManyToOne - its related entity will have "relation id" and foreign key.

---

> Você pode omitir @JoinColumn em uma relação @ManyToOne / @OneToMany. @OneToMany não pode existir sem @ManyToOne. Se você quiser usar @OneToMany, @ManyToOne é necessário. No entanto, o inverso não é necessário: se você se preocupa apenas com o relacionamento @ManyToOne, pode defini-lo sem ter @OneToMany na entidade relacionada. Onde você define @ManyToOne - sua entidade relacionada terá "id de relação" e chave estrangeira.

Ou seja, vc utilizou **`@OneToMany()`** na entidade Profissional, é obrigatório declarar **`@ManyToOne()`** em Idioma, pois o **TypeORM** monta toda a lógica no banco de dados em função deste relacionamento, como pode ser visto acima, se quiser pode declarar só o @ManyToOne() e omitir @OneToMany() que não terá problemas:

```
@Entity('idioma')
export class Idioma {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  lang: string;
  @Column()
  native: boolean;
  @ManyToOne(() => Profissional, profissional => profissional.lang)
  profissional: Profissional;
}

@Entity('Profissional')
export class Profissional {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  ...
  @OneToMany(() => Idioma, idioma => idioma.id, {
    cascade: true
  })
  lang: Idioma[];
  ...
}
```